# Camel: define jms queue name from properites file

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel

I'm trying to definejms listener with configurable queue name in camel in spring dsl. 
Approach I've followed with hardcoded value is next:

```
<from uri="jms:queue:update.q?messageConverter=#messageConverter"/>
```

and that works fine for queue name `update.q`

To use configurable queue name I've tried next approach:

```
<from uri="jms:queue:${update.q}?messageConverter=#messageConverter"/>
```

but it start listening to queue named `${update.q}` instead of value from proprties file.

Any ideas how to configure jms queue name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<from uri="jms:queue:{{update.q}}?messageConverter=#messageConverter"/>
```

and add "properties" bean

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:myproperties.properties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I have pring property definition which works fine for `${}`. I also have `<propertyPlaceholder/>` defined within `camelContext`, but when I switch to `{{}}` I get file not found. My property file is located externally and I use `value="file:///opt/java/my.properties"`, which does not work for camel property placeholder, but works for spring. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer? See more info in http://camel.apache.org/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your wildcard notation to Spring style:

```
<from uri="jms:queue:{{update.q}}?messageConverter=#messageConverter"/>
```

Then, make sure your properties file is registered by a Spring property placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///opt/java/my.properties" />
```

Finally, make sure your project includes the necessary Spring Camel integration dependency, e.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```